OpenSearch-Dashboards Alerting Action Throttling not working
I have multiple monitors set up, from type “Per query monitor” and with defining method either “Visual editor” or “Extraction query editor”. I set up Triggers with Actions to send notification mails to specific channels. The triggers and mailing notifications itself are working properly but the given value of 60 minutes inside “Throttle actions to only trigger every” and the activated Throttling option doesnt have the desired result. I still get way more than one mail per 60 minutes if the condition is triggered. Even if I use the maximum amount of throttling time of 1440 minutes I get too much mails. I think the option does not have any effect at all.
I am using OpenSearch 2.17.1

